# Laravel - Passing two variables to controller makes another page break

Tags: php, laravel

I have encountered a problem that has really confused me. I've been trying to fix it, but the way that works, I don't want.

So, I passing two variables to my ThreadController; 'category' and 'threadTitle' in the following way:

```
Route::get('/{category}/{threadTitle}', 'ThreadController@viewThread');
```

Just for testing purposes, I'm outputting the passed through variables out to the web page.

```
{{ $category.$threadTitle }}
```

Everything works fine, they're outputted. Unfortunately, this also breaks my new thread page, which routes are the following:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'thread'], function() {
    Route::get('/new', function() {
        return view('thread/new');
    });

    Route::get('/new', 'CategoryController@listCategoriesOnAddThread');
    Route::post('/new', 'CategoryController@addThread');
});
```

On the new thread page, the routes are outputted instead of the form. So, 'threadnew' is shown.

I did have a fix where I changed my category route to:

```
Route::get('/category/{category}/{threadTitle}', 'ThreadController@viewThread');
```

That works fine, nothing breaks. However, I don't want to use that way, I'd rather just have {category}/{threadTitle}

I'm really stuck right now and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have two `thread/new` routes there. As for dynamic routes just place it under any static route defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a general route placed before the specific ones, that catches every url with two segments. Just place the

```
Route::get('/{category}/{threadTitle}', 'ThreadController@viewThread');
```

below the specific routes and everything should work fine.

Comment: I honestly did not try that! Everything seems to be working fine now. Thank you =)

Comment: Glad I could help :)